# Why do the principal components in PCA always pass through the center of the data

Tags: pca, geometry

I am trying to figure out why do the principal components in a PCA analysis always pass through the centroid of the input data.

The books and articles all mention that the components pass through the data centroid but no explanation is usually provided for this. Does it have something to do with that there is some property where the axes that maximises the variance should pass through the data centroid?

Comment: They don't.  All components, *by definition*, originate at the origin.  If you have arranged for the origin to coincide with the data centroid, well then--they all pass through the centroid.

Comment: @whuber Many thanks for your comment. My confusion stems from when we are doing PCA without centering the data. There are many excellent posts on this site about the implications and I grasp most of them, I think. I have read on some online blogs explaining PCA that if we do not centre the data, the first component will be in the direction of the mean of the data. I really have been struggling for the whole day trying to figure out why this would be the case.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify that point.  It currently states "components"--in the plural--pass through the centroid, but now you seem to want to ask only about the first one.  I am curious what blogs you refer to, because it is definitely not that case that any component must pass through the centroid.  Are you sure you are remembering them correctly?

Comment: @whuber I will update with more links. I, of course, may have misunderstood due to the gap in my understanding. I will update as soon as I can collect all those links again. I should have saved them.

Comment: If we create some data x_1 = N(0,a) and  x_2 = b with b<<a, would the first PC be aligned along the huge variation along the x_1 axis or the tiny offset of the x_2 axis? The answer should be clearly no. I guess that your sources speak about the first PC *approximately* passing trough the data centroid.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings It started with the wikipedia article which states "Given a set of points in Euclidean space, the first principal component corresponds to a line that passes through the multidimensional mean and minimizes the sum of squares of the distances of the points from the line. The second principal component corresponds to the same concept after all correlation with the first principal component has been subtracted.." Regarding your comment, what did you mean the "answer be clearly no."? I am still confused as to why the PC should pass approximately or exactly through the centroid.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings It also goes on later to say "If mean subtraction is not performed, the first principal component might instead correspond more or less to the mean of the data. A mean of zero is needed for finding a basis that minimizes the mean square error of the approximation of the data.". which corresponds to what you said about the first PC passing approximately through the data centroid. Although the reason for that is still unclear. Is it because the mean is sort of the most basic solution to the MSE problem?

Comment: I see that answer 'the answer is no' to a multiple choice question was a bit weird. The 'no' was a bit fast reaction pointing to the statement that the 1st PC goes trough the mean. The example, imagining a very small difference of the mean with 0 in comparison to the variance clearly shows that this is not true. --- Yes, the mean does influence the raw 2nd moment, $\mu_2$ (note: not really variance). You've got $\mu_2(\vec{X}+\mu_2{\mu}) = \mu_2(\vec{X}) + \vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{\mu}$. So, if $\mu \neq 0$ then it has a influence. If large influence, then 1st PC 'more or less' points to the mean.

Comment: not editable after 5mins. It should have been $\mu_2(\vec{X}+\vec{\mu}) = \mu_2(\vec{X}) + \vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{\mu}$ The second moment has the distributive property with respect to summation.